# One-liner to get service startup type

Tags: powershell, command-line, salt-stack

liner that I am writing to do a check with salt and a windows.. i think its just syntax and I am pretty new to powershell, any assistance would be great.

```
powershell -NoProfile "if ( Get-Service someCoolService -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -And if (someCoolService.StartUpType -ne "Disabled") { Write-Output "True" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use WMI for this:

```
powershell -NoProfile "&{![bool](Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter \"Name='yourService' AND StartMode='Disabled'\")}"
```

Assuming you're talking about the SaltStack config management system you should also be able to [run PowerShell code directly](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html) by specifying the `shell` parameter:

```
salt '*' cmd.run "![bool](Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter \"Name='yourService' AND StartMode='Disabled'\"" shell='powershell'
```

Comment: I had the salt part correct, and I didnt understand the syntax error that well. I attempted to fix it to no avail since i am still new and trying to understand powershell. Thank you for showing me about the WMI for this. Google had examples but they werent that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, its a syntax error. If you want to fix it yourself, I'd suggest you to open a powershell window the next time, and execute everything after "powershell -Noprofile" -> since this part is not needed if you're in a powershell window. (To run powershell, just type powershell in command prompt or open a powershell window from among your applications).

Anyway, let me help you with this one, while you can use what I mentioned before for the times you're stuck later.

```
powershell -profile if(( Get-Service someCoolService -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -And (someCoolService.StartUpType -ne "Disabled")) { Write-Output "True" }
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I opened PS and did all that however the error I did not understand, I googled examples andit never really worked correctly. Wasn't sure what the error meant either. But Thankyou.

Comment: Great! Glad to know it helped:)